# Dhampir and Lifelink

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, undead, healing, negative-energy

The Dhampir race has a negative energy affinity, which means negative energy heals them and positive hurts them, as if they were undead.

The [Life-Link](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/mysteries/paizo-oracle-mysteries/life/) ability from shamans and oracles states that it heals wounded creatures, and does not specify energy type, and does not state that the linked creature needs to be alive.

How does this ability interact with people who have negative energy affinities? Does it heal or hurt them?

Comment: You may also be interested in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102828/8610).

Comment: Yep. I am already aware of that interaction, and that it makes it function like undead. This does not specify if it works or doesnt work on undead. Dhampir is the most plausible case this would occur, but I am curious if it works on undead in general as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lifelink behaves the same regardless of what creature is bonded. So whether living, dead, undead, dhampir, or even a construct, lifelink heals the target for 5 when the oracle is damaged for 5. It simply has no rule suggesting otherwise.

Moreover, it’s not at all clear what the ”inverse” would even be here. If anything, the ability would just fail—but if that was what was intended, it would have been trivial for lifelink to specify “living,” which would exclude constructs and the undead. Dhampir would still be affected, but there would be cause to consider whether or not a house rule on that point would be appropriate. As it is, though, it just works, and there isn’t really any suggestion it shouldn’t.